# MySQL create table one to many, what is the best option below?

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database

I have below data and using mysql.  Person_name is unique and TelephoneNumbers are unique per person.

```
Person_name1=TelephoneNumber1, TelephoneNumber2, TelephoneNumber3...
Person_name2=TelephoneNumber4, TelephoneNumber5, TelephoneNumber6...
```

Option 1. Create 1:Many master and child table.

```
CREATE TABLE Person (
personName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY (id),
UNIQUE KEY personName (personName)
);

CREATE TABLE Telephone (
telephoneNumber int,
mappingId int,
PRIMARY KEY (telephoneNumber),
 foreign key(mappingId) references Person(id)
);
```

Option 2. Create one table with personName, telephoneNumber as Composite Key.

```
CREATE TABLE
Person_Telephone (
    personName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    telephoneNumber int NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(personName, telephoneNumber)
);
```

Option 1 is it over complicating creating two tables for just two fields?
Option 2 looks perfect and will there be any issues if Option 2 chosen over Option 1?

Comment: Can users have more than 1 phone number?  That is the only issue with option 2 that I can think of.

Comment: @Jane each person(user) have more than 1 phone number.  Bob, 999999|Bob, 888888|Bob 777777|Dan 6666666|Dan 33333333

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The option 2 gives you duplicate persons that you must control in every query.

The best is have the entities separate, it's a classic 1-N relation

Answer (score 2):

Since users can have multiple phone numbers, I think 2 tables would be the best solution.

```
CREATE TABLE person (
PRIMARY KEY (id) AUTO_INCREMENT,
person_name VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE phone_number (
PRIMARY KEY (id) AUTO_INCREMENT,
phone_number VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (person_id) REFERENCES person(id)
)
```

Now you can simply `JOIN` the tables like this:

```
SELECT
t1.id,
t1.person_name,
t2.phone_number
FROM person t1
LEFT JOIN phone_number t2
ON (t1.id = t2.person_id);
```